# Shiny server installation on REHL 7 AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny, shiny-server

I followed these commands to install R and Shiny server on REHL 7 AWS.

```
sudo yum update 
yum install wget gcc pcre-devel libXt-devel cairo-devel pango-devel 
pango libpng-devel curl-devel unixODBC-devel python-devel java-1.8.0-
openjdk-devel xz-devel
yum groupinstall "Development tools"

wget http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
tar xzvf bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
cd bzip2-1.0.6
make -f Makefile-libbz2_so
make clean
make
make -n install
make install
cd ~

wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.3.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf R-3.3.2.tar.gz
cd R-3.3.2
./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no
make
make install

cp -r /usr/local/bin/R /usr/local/sbin/R
cp -r /usr/local/bin/Rscript /usr/local/sbin/Rscript

--Installing R packages 
R
install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown', 'Cairo', 'png', 'rJava', 
'RCurl'))

--Changing folder permissions

chmod 777 -R /usr/local/bin
chmod 777 -R /usr/local/sbin
chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib64/R
chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib64/R/library
chmod 777 /usr/local/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths

--shiny server installation

wget https://download3.rstudio.org/centos5.9/x86_64/shiny-server-
1.5.1.834-rh5-x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install --nogpgcheck shiny-server-1.5.1.834-rh5-x86_64.rpm

R CMD javareconf

chmod 777 /usr/local/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths
```

Everything ran fine with some warnings. But the shiny-server.service file is missing. When I try to execute

```
systemctl restart shiny-server
```

it says: Failed to restart shiny-server.service: Unit not found.

I also tried installing the newer version of R (3.4.1) and Shiny server(shiny-server-1.5.3.838-rh5-x86_64.rpm) but I am still getting the same error. This is the message I got when I installed shiny server:

```
 /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.kIBODd: line 62: initctl: command not found
 /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.kIBODd: line 65: initctl: command not found
 Verifying  : shiny-server-1.5.1.834-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                 
 1/1

 Installed:
 shiny-server.x86_64 0:1.5.1.834-1
```

Also I noticed that shiny-server.service is missing in /etc/systemd/system folder. Has anyone resolved this or knows how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
As suggested in https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/316,
entering these three lines manually solved it for me:

```
sudo cp /opt/shiny-server/config/systemd/shiny-server.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl enable shiny-server
sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```